# Meta query with order by another custom field

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order, sort

Edit: I will try to explain in detail my problem.
I am working on a portfolio site. There are a few custom post types: Projects, Publications, Exhibitions, Lectures, and Slides. The home page consists of the following sections:

- slider with Slides
- **portfolio consisting of:**
- selected (marked by Client) Projects, Publications, Exhibitions, and Lectures
- and remaining Projects, Publications, Exhibitions, and Lectures
- awards section

**Now, I have a problem with the portfolio section.** It is to be paged in order to use Infinite Scroll by Desandro - the next posts are loaded after clicking the "Load more" button.
The first 10 posts are these marked 'selected' (1st custom field) by the Client in a particular order determined by the 2nd custom field (from 1 to 10).
The remaining posts are to be ordered by date descending.

I used wp_query to query custom posts and meta_query to get these 'selected' posts on top and sort them ascending. I tried to sort the remaining posts by date but I'm stuck.

Take a look at my wp_query args:

```
'post_type' => array( 'projekty', 'publikacje', 'wystawy', 'wyklady' ),
'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'home_rest' => array(
        'key' => 'sticky_home',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
    'home_sticky' => array(
        'key' => 'sticky_home',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
'orderby' => array(
    'home_rest' => 'DESC',
    'home_sticky' => 'ASC',
    ),
'posts_per_page' => 10, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
```

So I achieved the first goal (you can see red blocks representing 'selected' posts here: http://redesigned.pl/_sts/bxbstudio/strona-glowna-infinitemasonry/.

I thought I would be able to do this multiple `orderby` sorting. Firstly, sort by `sticky_home` field (true/false field) to get selected posts on top; Secondly, sort them ascending by `sticky_home_order` field; Thirdly, sort posts with `sticky_home` marked `false` descending by date published. Do you think it is possible to get all of that in one query? or perhaps there is another way to achieve that?

I'll appreciate any help.

Edit: I am no experienced PHP programmer. Having read through various content on stack exchange, I think that perhaps using `usort` could be the way. together with `get_posts`? but on the other hand, pagination will brake..

Comment: this query will be slow/expensive, if you could store `sticky_home` as a taxonomy term, and have 2 terms `sticky_home`, and `not_sticky_home`, then this would see a major speed boost and be able to handle more visitors at the same time. Also, your use of `paged` implies that this isn't a second query on the page, but a replacement query. Is there a reason you didn't use `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: @TomJNowell There will be 2 more queries on that page not related with that one, that is why I didn't use `pre_get_posts`.
`sticky_home` as a taxonomy term? for each custom post that is queried?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling and searching a bit I managed to have:

- 'selected' 10 posts on top
- 'remaining' posts below sorted descending by date

Unfortunately the 'selected' posts are in descending order ... here is my query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'projekty', 'publikacje', 'wystawy', 'wyklady' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'sticky_home_order',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'sticky_home_order',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value' => 'DESC',
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 
        'date' => 'DESC'
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 20, 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
);
```

Comment: @Marco thanks for the edit. It would have been simpler to just add an extra backtick though: jakesh had put two at the start and end of the code block whereas the markdown here uses three.